# django: Не отображаются поля ввода данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Django 4.2, Python 3.11

Это тот же самый код, только переписанный после переустановки самой Windows и PyCharm. Проблема такова: при запуске в проекте не отображаются поля ввода данных. Все возможные способы уже испробованы. Как видите, проблема всё ещё не решена.

*models.py*

```py
from django.db import models 

class Homework(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    page = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    exerc_number = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    exerc_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.exerc_number
```

*urls.py*

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.index, name='home'),
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),]
```

*views.py*

```py
import data as data
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Homework

def index (request):
    return HttpResponse("Введите информацию")

def home_page(request):
    data = Homework.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home_page.html', {'data': data})
```

Шаблон HTML:

*home_page.html*

```html
{% for b in data %}
<a href="{{b.homework.url}}">b.author</a>
<a href="{{b.homework.url}}">b.subject</a>
<a href="{{b.homework.url}}">b.grade</a>
<a href="{{b.homework.url}}">b.page</a>
<a href="{{b.homework.url}}">b.exerc_number</a>
<img src= "{{ b.exerc_photo.html }}">
{% endfor %}
< method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
```

Результат запуска кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никаких полей, только текст. Пожалуйста, подскажите решение моей проблемы.

Comment: Приведите HTML шаблон полностью.

Comment: В приведённом фрагменте шаблона вы просто отображаете данные о каждом объекте в `Homework.objects.all()`, и, видимо, их там просто нет, из-за этого ничего и не отображается.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, вы **перепутали модели и формы.** Модели нужны для того, чтобы хранить данные, а вот формы как раз имеют поля ввода и нужны для заполнения.

- Вам нужно создать новый файл forms.py
- Создать там класс формы,определить поля.
- Импортировать форму во views и передать ее в Html.
- Цикл уже будет не нужен.

Comment: Исправила, но все тщетно...